# How to detect that document's content is loaded?

Tags: javascript, load, frame, doc, readystate

I want to detect when a document has finished loading all its content. The document is coming from Main doc's first frame i.e

```
var frameList = window.top.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
if(frameList.length == 0)
{
     frameList = window.top.document.getElementsByTagName("frame");
}
var frame = frameList[0];
var doc = ((frame.contentWindow) || (frame.contentDocument));
if (doc.document) doc = doc.document;

var readyState = doc.readyState;
```

Now, this ready state sometimes coming as loading , in this case i am having no trouble in playing with document's Element. But the problem comes when this ready state is coming as complete in that case i am not able to get control over its element. I tried to put a timer on ready state with 1ms but that doesn't helped me out. Timer i put is something like this :

```
doc.prevState = readyState;
window.top.setTimeout(window.top.timeLoop,1,doc,fName);

function timeLoop(doc,fName)
{
     var state1 = doc.readyState;
     if(state1 != doc.prevState)
     {
          obj.doc.prevState = state1;
          // Calling a function to check its state again. If state equals                 loaded or interactive or complete i am calling my desired funtion.
     }
     else
     {
          window.top.setTimeout(window.top.timeLoop2,1,doc,fName);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Is the iFrame content from the same origin as the parent page?

Comment: `<iframe onload="top.iAmDone()"` - or in the page in the iframe: `window.onload=function() { top.iAmDone() }`